# How do you create a void method that reads a file and stores the information into an array then displays the text from the method into a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

So I've created a method that reads a file and for every line in that text file, the method inputs them into an array. Now i'm trying to figure how I can display that entire method (readFile method) into my JTextArea. Help Please?

```
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.Scanner; 


public class NameViewer {

JTextField nameTF;
JTextArea displayArea;
NameRecord[] nameList ;

public static void main( String[] arg ) {
    NameViewer app = new NameViewer() ;

}

public NameViewer() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Name Surfer" ) ;
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) ;

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() ;
    mainPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ) ;

    displayArea = new JTextArea(25, 50) ;
    displayArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( displayArea ) ;
    mainPanel.add( BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollPane ) ;

    displayArea.setText(readFile());

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel() ;
    controlPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 3) ) ;

    nameTF = new JTextField( 7 ) ;
    controlPanel.add( nameTF ) ;

    JButton find = new JButton(" Find " );
    controlPanel.add(find) ;
    find.addActionListener( new Listener());

    JButton match = new JButton(" Match " );
    controlPanel.add(match) ;
    match.addActionListener( new Listener());

    mainPanel.add( BorderLayout.SOUTH, controlPanel ) ;

    frame.add( mainPanel ) ;
    frame.setVisible( true ) ;
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack() ;
}

public class Listener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {


    }
}

public String readFile() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String inputLine;
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File ("baby-names.txt"));

        int i = 0;
        int num = inFile.nextInt();
        nameList = new NameRecord[num];

        while ( inFile.hasNext() ) {
            inputLine = inFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(nameList);        

            nameList[i] = new NameRecord(inputLine);
            displayArea.append(nameList[i] +"\n");
            i++ ;
        }
    } catch(IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io) ;
    }
     return sb.toString();

}  // readFile()


}
```

heres my NameRecord:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
A class to represent the data for one name over the 
decades.
KEEP THIS IN A SEPARATE FILE!
*/
public class NameRecord {

private String name ;
private int[] rank ;
public static final int START = 1900 ;
public static final int DECADES = 11 ;

/**
 * 
 * @param record
 */
public NameRecord(String record){
    //use a Scanner to get the data from the record
    Scanner line = new Scanner (record);
    name = line.next();

    rank = new int[DECADES] ;
    for(int i=0; i<DECADES; i++)
        rank[i] = line.nextInt();
}

public String getName() {
    return name ;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public int getRank(int d) {
    int decadeRank = rank[d];
    return decadeRank;
}
/** returns the best decade
*
* @return the best decade
*/  
public int bestDecade() {
    int best = rank[0];
    for(int i=1; i<DECADES; i++)
        if(rank[i] > best)
            best = rank[i];
    return best;
}
/** toString method for NameRecord
*
* @return student's name and rank
*/  
public String toString() {
    String result = getName() ;

    for(int i=0; i<DECADES; i++)
        result = result + " " + rank[i] ;

    return result ;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see where you are using the array to set the text, I'll just recommend this

```
while ( inFile.hasNext() ) {
        inputLine = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(inputLine);       

        nameList[i] = new NameRecord(inputLine);
        displayArea.append(nameList[i] + "\n");
        i++ ;
}
```

I just added an `append` statement, that will append to the text area.

Also keep in mind, you should override the `toString()` method in your `NameRecord` so you get your desired String output

You don't need to pass an argument of `fileName` to the method, since you're already using the literal in the method.

Another suggestion, make the method return a String

```
 String readFile() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String inputLine;
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File ("baby-names.txt"));

            int i = 0;
            int num = inFile.nextInt();
            nameList = new NameRecord[num];

            while ( inFile.hasNext() ) {
                inputLine = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);       

                nameList[i] = new NameRecord(inputLine);
                sb.append(nameList[i]);
                i++ ;
        }
    } catch(IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io) ;
    }

    return sb.toString()'
}
```

Then in your constructor

```
displayArea.setText(readFile());
```

**Edit: for desired result** try this

```
String readFile() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("FIND RESULTS FOR Trinity\n\n");
        sb.append("Decade\tRank\n");
        sb.append("------\t-----\n");
        try {
            String inputLine;
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File ("baby-names.txt"));

            int i = 0;
            int num = inFile.nextInt();
            nameList = new NameRecord[num];

            while ( inFile.hasNext() ) {
                inputLine = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);       

                nameList[i] = new NameRecord(inputLine);
                sb.append(nameList[i].getDecade() + "\t" + nameList[i].getRank() + "\n");
                i++ ;
        }
    } catch(IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io) ;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is assuming you have a `getDecade()` and `getRank()` in your `NameRecord` class

Edit: Complete runnable program

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameViewer {

    JTextField nameTF;
    JTextArea displayArea;
    NameRecord[] namesArray;


    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        NameViewer app = new NameViewer();

    }

    public NameViewer() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Name Surfer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        displayArea = new JTextArea(25, 50);
        displayArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(displayArea);
        mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollPane);

        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        nameTF = new JTextField(7);
        controlPanel.add(nameTF);

        JButton find = new JButton(" Find ");
        controlPanel.add(find);
        find.addActionListener(new Listener());

        JButton match = new JButton(" Match ");
        controlPanel.add(match);
        match.addActionListener(new Listener());

        mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, controlPanel);

        read("names.txt");

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public class Listener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }

    private void read(String filename) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String inputLine;
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            int i = 0;
            int num = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine().trim());
            namesArray = new NameRecord[num];

            String inputString;
            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                inputString = inFile.nextLine();
                namesArray[i] = new NameRecord(inputString);
                displayArea.append(namesArray[i].toString() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io);
        }
    }  // readFile()
}

public class NameRecord {

    private String name;
    private final static int NUM_OF_DECADES = 11;
    private int[] ranks;

    public NameRecord(String inputString) {
        String[] split = inputString.split("\\s+");

        this.name = split[0];

        ranks = new int[NUM_OF_DECADES];

        for (int i = 1; i < NUM_OF_DECADES; i++) {
            ranks[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public int getHighRank(int d) {
        int decadeRank = ranks[d];
        return decadeRank;
    }

    public int[] getRank(){
        return ranks;
    }

    public int bestDecade() {
        int best = ranks[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DECADES; i++) {
            if (ranks[i] > best) {
                best = ranks[i];
            }
        }
        return best;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = getName();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DECADES; i++) {
            result = result + " " + ranks[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: is the first number of the file the number of names in the file?

Comment: never mind I fixed the error. just a typo. but my main question is how do I display it in my gui?

Comment: Try to change this `mainPanel.add( BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollPane )`  to this `mainPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER )`. CHnaged the order. And try and `pack()` before you `setVisible()`.

Comment: I mean the gui layout is fine. but the text is not displaying in my jtextarea when I run my program

Comment: You need to call the method.

Comment: I havent done the listener yet, thats for something else, I just want the text from a file to display when I open it. Here's a link on what im trying to do if that helps explain it. http://www.cs.plu.edu/courses/csce144/fall2013/labs/lab11/NamePopularity.html

Comment: You have a lot more work to do to get that output. First think you need is a JPanel to paint. Override the `paintComponent` method and draw in that method

Comment: I can already display text in my jtextarea, but the text I need in particular is the text coming from readFile. I tried that setText before but it's saying that it cannot find the readFile variable

Comment: In order to get that graphical representation, you need to actually draw the output

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking something different

Comment: I tried displayArea.setText(readFile()); so it displays the mthod but I need parameters that is a string. What would I use as a parameter?

Comment: I already explained that you don't need a parameter for the method. Just delete the String fileName from the parameter. See my edit

Comment: I do have them, but I dont need them yet. All I need to do is display all the names like in Part 2 # 2. Haha your going too far xD

Comment: Im just on part 2 number 2 xD I dont need to figure out the others one just yet.

Comment: Try out my method, the last one

Comment: This is the error I get when theres no parameter. NameViewer.java:37: error: method readFile in class NameViewer cannot be applied to given types;
  displayArea.setText(readFile());
                      ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
Process javac exited with code 1

Comment: Look at my method. Try and use the last one. Just copy and paste it

Comment: actually im getting a different error..I fixed what ur talking about but heres my new error: xception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at NameRecord.<init>(NameRecord.java:22)
 at NameViewer.readFile(NameViewer.java:82)
 at NameViewer.<init>(NameViewer.java:37)
 at NameViewer.main(NameViewer.java:20)

Comment: Is the first line in the file the number of names?

Comment: However you obtain the data `decade` and `rank` from the class. Use that.  Also, show your file

Comment: I just added my other java class so if it makes sense for you

Comment: its too long to display here but here it is the link to it. http://www.cs.plu.edu/courses/csce144/fall2013/labs/lab11/baby-names.txt

Comment: What do the different numbers in the lines mean?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what your code is trying to do. Sorry.

Comment: this whole program is just confusing haha I got upperclass students in here helping me and theyre confused...im a freshman and theyre all juniors so how am I suppose to figure it out if they cant even -.- lol xD

Comment: I will work on it later today when I have time. I'll and post a solution for you. Not too much time right now :)

Comment: Can you just explain what the numbers in the rows mean.

Comment: You really weren't that far off. I Edited my answer with the complete running program. You can compare the difference. You really weren't that far off :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you output a String array from readFile method, and call it from the main.

```
String [] storage = readFile(fileName);


for(int i=0; i<storage.length; i++){
    displayArea.append(storage[i] + "\n");
}
```

Adding \n is optional if you want each element to be on separate lines.

OR, if you just want to do it in the readFile method,

```
 while ( inFile.hasNext() ) {
        inputLine = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(inputLine);       

        nameList[i] = new NameRecord(inputLine);
        displayArea.append(nameList[i] +"\n");
        i++ ;
    }
```

Comment: I get an error for that. NameViewer.java:68: error: incompatible types
  String [] storage = readFile(fileName);
                              ^
  required: String[]
  found:    void
1 error

Comment: "I'd suggest you output a String array from readFile method, and call it from the main"

Comment: how do you output a string array?

Comment: nevermind I got it. but how do I call it from the main? I keep getting errors that the variable is missing